# Android Fragments, FlashLight

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new in Android Development, I am developing a flash light app using fragments with Tab-Views, flashlight only turn on and off on the first tab only  i.e

@Override

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { 

        switch (position){               
            case 0: return Strobes.newInstance("SecondFragment, Build 2");
            case 1: return Effects.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Build3");
            case 2: return Torch.newInstance("FirstFragment, Build 1");
            default: return null;//return Torch.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
        }
    }
```

Problem: Whoever is on case 0:  has the ability to turn ON and OFF the flashlight. Others are just performing the button click events but not turning the flashlight ON and OFF.  I mean case 1: & case 2: are just firing their on click events but not turning on the Flashlight. 
Can anyone tell me the solution please?﻿

Comment: Make sure you release the camera when switching fragments.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! , but whenever i use camera.release(); my app crashes i.e unfortunately, application has stopped.